# Setting state from Firebase data results in blank data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to load all 'groups' from my Firebase once my React app loads but I'm am getting weird behavior. It loads them in correctly at first so if I have 3 groups saved in my database it'll show 1, 2, 3, 4 like this:
[image]

but as soon as I add another group to the list it does this:

[image]

The code I have to load the groups on componentDidMount is this:

```
componentDidMount(){        
    this.setGroups();
}
setGroups(){
    const groupRef = fire.database().ref('groups');
    const groupArray = [];
    const idArray = [];
    groupRef.on('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(group => {
            console.log('groupid: ' + group.key);
            idArray.push(group.key);
            let addGroup = {
                id: group.key,
                name: group.val().name
            }
            if(groupArray.length !== idArray.length){
                groupArray.push(addGroup);
                console.log('pushed');
            }
        })

        this.setState(previousState => ({
            groups: groupArray
        }));
    })
}
```

Then this is how I handle a group being added:

```
handleGroupAdd = (group) => {
    const groupRef = fire.database().ref('groups').child(group.id).set({
        name: group.name,
        id: group.id
    });
    this.setState(previousState => ({
        groups: [...previousState.groups, group]
    }));

    this.handleClose();
};
```

The firebase is holding the data correctly, no duplicate objects so its just the rendering of the groups that is getting messed up. Which I'm guessing is the state getting screwed up on the add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Explanation of your issue :**

You are starting a snapshot listener by using `groupRef.on`, this listener calls a function each time your `groupRef` content has changed, it is then pushing all values to `groupArray` each time.
Because `groupArray` is declared outside of the snapshot function, its content is kept between updates.

**Here's what's happening :**

1. First render :

`setGroup` is called => `groupArray` = [1,2,3,4];

2. Add group :

`groupRef` listener is triggered => push [1,2,3,4,5] to `groupArray` => `groupArray` = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5] => state update in `handleGroupAdd`  => `groups` state = [...prevState, 5];

### **To fix your issue you can either :**

- **Call the snapshot listener only once :**

`groupRef.once('value', snapshot => {...`

- **Or rely on listeners only :**

move groupArray declaration in the snapshot function :

```
groupRef.on('value', snapshot => {
  let groupArray = [];
  ...
```

and remove the state update in `handleGroupAdd`;

I advise you to rely on listeners to keep consistency between your front and the database, there are many other listeners to work with instead of the 'value' one, [you can read the official doc for more info about working with lists of realtime database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)

Comment: Great thank you for the explanation also! Really helpful! I will try it out tonight and see how it works